# Getting "invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound" from PDO

Tags: php, pdo

My code reports this error:

> invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound on line 6 which is statement->execute();

Code

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM post where id=:id';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$posts = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<?php require 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">Comment on Post <?= $posts->post ?> </div>

   </div>
</div>

<?php require 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I just want to fetch the data in post where the id

[image]

Comment: did you `var_dump` `$posts`?

Comment: The error is pretty explicit, no parameters are being bound... you've put an `:id` placeholder into the query (`SELECT * FROM post where id=:id`) but never actually bound the data to it.

Comment: You either need to bind `$id` or pass it to `execute` as an array as it needs to replace `:id`.

Comment: consider using better titles for questions to increase the chance of someone answering

Comment: Try to change the title to something like this: "How to select a row with matching ID" and read the guide [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/515960)

Answer (score 4):

At least you are using prepared statements, but in your prepare you have `id=:id` so you need to pass a value into the execute to be used in the place of `:id`...

```
$statement->execute(['id' => $id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot bindParam()
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
require 'db.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM post where id=:id';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$statement->execute();
```

Comment: why this may work - you should add an explanation for future users to understand the code - code-only answers aren't answers IMO